Puppet: Check for defined Service
I want to check for a defined service, and then do something.
This is working for classes, but not for services or packages.
The Manifest:
  if defined(Class['some::class']) {
    a_module::some_action {'foo': }
  }


This is wroking perfectly fine.
But if I check for a Service it is just not working.
  if defined(Service['postgresql']) {
    a_module::some_action {'foo': }
  }

I've checked, that the service is existant on the client
$ cat /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/state/resources.txt | grep postgresql
package[postgresql]
service[postgresql]


What am I missing?
Any hint is very much appreciated!

The defined function generally should not be used.  It especially should not be used to test for resource instances having been defined, because that is sensitive to manifest evaluation order, and evaluation order is very hard to predict or to keep stable across changes to the manifest set.

What am I missing?

Your situation is likely a case in point: when your defined(Service['postgresql']) call is evaluated during catalog building, that service has not yet been declared, but such a declaration is evaluated later in the same catalog-building run.
Puppet cannot solve this issue without altogether removing defined()'s ability to test for declared resources.*  That would require deferring evaluation of defined() calls until after all resources have been declared, but defined() is used, generally, to determine which resources to declare.

This is working for classes

I dislike defined for classes (and resource types), too, but it doesn't have the same problem there that is described above.  In those cases, it does not test the catalog under construction, but rather the contents of available modules.  This is not sensitive to evaluation order.

Any hint is very much appreciated!

Puppet's manifest language and catalog language are not scripting languages, and trying to treat them as such tends to turn out poorly.  If you need a particular resource to be declared then ensure that it is declared.  If not, then don't rely on it being declared.
This is largely a question of the design of your whole manifest set.  There is no silver bullet, but there are design strategies that help with these kinds of considerations.  The Roles & Profiles pattern is perhaps the most popular of these.

*This would be ok by me, but I imagine Puppet, Inc. is concerned about such a move breaking existing code.
